# Summarizing temporal change in identifier occurrence

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with job ids (varchar) per date and user ID.

```
User    Date        Job
mid1    2019-10-10  jid1
mid1    2019-10-10  jid2
mid1    2019-10-10  jid3
mid1    2019-10-10  jid4
mid1    2019-10-10  jid5
mid1    2019-10-11  jid3
mid1    2019-10-11  jid5
mid1    2019-10-11  jid6
mid1    2019-10-11  jid7
mid1    2019-10-11  jid8
mid1    2019-10-11  jid9
mid1    2019-10-12  jid3
mid1    2019-10-12  jid9
mid1    2019-10-12  jid10
mid2    2019-10-10  jid100
mid2    2019-10-10  jid101
mid2    2019-10-10  jid102
...
```

Now I need a table with the number of new ("Incoming") and completed ("Outgoing") jobs in the time sequence of the data, per user.

```
User    Date       Jobs  Incoming  Outgoing
mid1    2019-10-10   5     5           0
mid1    2019-10-11   6     4           3
mid1    2019-10-12   3     1           4
mid2    ...
```

It would also be great if it would only count unique job id (there are duplicates). But otherwise I can eliminate them beforehand.

Can this be done using Teradata SQL?

Comment: How do you define *Incoming* and  *Outgoing*? Same job for consecutive dates, 1st day *Incoming* and last day *Outgoing*? What if there are gaps? And what are *duplicate* job ids?

Comment: Incoming: An id present on the current day that is absent in the day before.

Comment: Outgoing: An id missing on the current day that was present the day before.
Gaps should not be a problem because terminated jobs cannot be reactivated, and if they do anyway, they can be counted using the same method. Duplicate job ids would be if in Table 1 a line is occurring more that once. But it's actually not an issue with the data.

Comment: Final question regarding gaps: Is there always one row per day per job, e.g. no missing rows for weekends?

Comment: There are no missing rows for weekends. Always a row per day and job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
   User
  ,Date
  ,Count(*) AS Jobs
   -- new jobs today
  ,Sum(firstdate) AS Incoming
   -- finished jobs today
  ,Sum(lastdate)
   -- finished jobs the day before
  ,Lag(Sum(lastdate),1,0) Over (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Date) AS Outgoing
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      User
     ,Job
     ,Date 
      -- flag indicating job is present on the current day but absent the day before
     ,CASE WHEN Date =  Lag(Date) Over (PARTITION BY User, job ORDER BY Date) + 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS firstdate
      -- flag indicating job is present on the current day but absent the day after
     ,CASE WHEN Date = Lead(Date) Over (PARTITION BY User, job ORDER BY Date) - 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS lastdate
   FROM your_table
   -- to remove duplicate rows add
   -- GROUP BY 1,2,3
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

If you're Teradata version doesn't support LAG/LEAD (i.e. < 16.10) you must rewrite it:

```
SELECT
   User
  ,Date
  ,Count(*) AS Jobs
   -- new jobs today
  ,Sum(firstdate) AS Incoming
   -- finished jobs today
  ,Sum(lastdate)
   -- finished jobs the day before
  ,Coalesce(Min(Sum(lastdate)) Over (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding), 0) AS Outgoing
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      User
     ,Job
     ,Date 
      -- flag indicating job is present on the current day but absent the day before
     ,CASE WHEN Date = Min(Date) Over (PARTITION BY User, job ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) + 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS firstdate
      -- flag indicating job is present on the current day but absent the day after
     ,CASE WHEN Date = Min(Date) Over (PARTITION BY User, job ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following ) - 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS lastdate
   FROM your_table
   -- to remove duplicate rows add
   -- GROUP BY 1,2,3
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Very cool Dieter...I was trying to figure this one out, but all I ended up with was a headache :)

Comment: Do you know if there is a DB / SQL Fiddle platform that supports Teradata?

Comment: @ravioli None I'm aware of. Should be simple using the Express version, but there's probably not enough demand for Teradata :-)